# Meteor.js how can I use templates with the same name, multiple times

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

How can I use the same template name multiple times across different files? I have the same template naming pattern for every page, and the problem is when for example `<template name="defaultContent"></template>` was already used on another page, it can't be used again.

example URLs:

```
/home
/home/first
/home/second
/home/third
```

homePage.html

```
/template: homePage
  template: default
  template: first
  template: second
  template: third
```

userPage.html

```
/template: userPage
  template: default
  template: first
  template: second
  template: third
```

Iron router code:

```
// mainpage
Router.route('/home', function () {
    this.render('homePage');
    this.render('default', {to: 'content'});
});

// subpages
Router.route('/home/:content', function () {
  this.render('homePage');
  var templateName = this.params.content;
  if(Template[templateName]){
    this.render(templateName, {to: 'content'});
  };
});
```

[update] By the way, that's how [Meteor kitchen](http://www.meteorkitchen.com/) solved this problem:

```
<template name="CoolPageSubPageBSubPageB1LoremIpsum">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define multiple templates with the same name.

Meteor defines your templates in a global object, `Template` (for example, `Template.homePage`). An object can't have multiple times the same field, so defining multiple times a single template would lead to errors (possibly silent ones).

Plus, how could the router know which `defaultContent` you are talking about?
How could you?

Instead of shadowing templates, you could simply define multiple templates (`Template.homeDefault`, `Template.userDefault`) which would allow you to debug them and refer to them easily.

Comment: That is exactly how I'm going to solve it, by prefixing template names with page name so it will be homeFirst, homeSecond, homeDefault, and so on. I'have written a simple rule for Iron router whch said: if you open url like: address.com/home/firstsubpage, then simply look for template firstsubpage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in one parent template per page. You add then your template inside the parent template in its HTML using  `{{> defaultContent}}` if the template you want to reuse is called "defaultContent".

Comment: It would be too easy, to be true ;)

Comment: That's true, however, and easy. I use this to reuse shared templates in different contexts. I just add parameters to my call like this `{{> mySharedTemplate mode="user"}}`

Comment: but templates can't be contained inside other templates like `<template>parent...<template>nested</...></...>`, and what I want to achieve is define multiple `<template name="default">` - for user, and another `<template name="default">` - for home

Comment: So I guess @Kyll solution is the way to go, even if I don't get why you **have to** proceed this way